# T-SQL: How to fill a column with user's department?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I realize that this task should be pretty simple but for some reason I can't figure it out for some time. Search for similar problems didn't help either.

So, let's say I have two tables: *Documents* and *DepartmentsAndUsers*.

```
--- Documents --- (one document could have any user as its author)
DocumentID   AuthorID   DepartemntID
1            User1      null
2            User2      null
3            User3      null
4            User1      null
5            User4      null

--- DepartmentsAndUsers --- (a user could be in any number of departments) 
DepartmentID   UserID
Dept1          User1
Dept1          User2
Dept1          User3
Dept2          User4
Dept2          User5
Dept3          User1
Dept3          User3
```

How do I fill *DepartemntID* column in *Documents* table with first (or any) of user's departments located in *DepartmentsAndUsers* table?

For example, User1 is in Dept1 and in Dept3 so *DepartmentID* for *Documents* 1 and 4 should be filled with Dept1 or Dept3 values.

Please don't think on this from the normalization point as I am unable to change any logic of the tables.

Any help or link to some solved solution with the same scenario would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Since a user can be in multiple departments, does it matter which one you put in the documents tables?  For User1, can they ALL say Dept1?  That's easy to do.  Otherwise there's no real way to identify which documents should get "Dept1" or "Dept3"

Comment: It doesn't matter. Any of depts will do.

Comment: it depends if you want it on the same row or if multiple rows are ok. If it's the latter, then a simple join will work. Otherwise you'll need a dynamic pivot or stuff the list of departments into one column

Comment: Well, the algorithm as I see it should be like this:
1) Look at the Documents table
2) Check first record (document 1)
3) Find who is author.
4) Find first user's departement.
5) Write it to the DepartemntID field of Document 1.
6) Repeat steps 1 to 5 for all other documents in Documents table.

But I can't figure how to do it.

Comment: i know you said ignore the normalization but... I can't.  this design is terrible and literally makes no sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with cte as( 
    select 
        UserID,
        max(DepartmentID) as DepartmentID
    from DepartmentsAndUsers
    group by UserID)

select 
    d.DocumentID,
    d.AuthorID,
    cte.DepartmentID
from Documents d
inner join cte on cte.UserID = d.AuthorID
```

Comment: This query will select the data and I need to update values in existing table like: update Documents set DepartemntID = ???

Comment: I got it now! This using of common table expression was exactly what I needed. With the whole expression you wrote I can now join my Documents table to your selection expression with "on Documents.ID = Selection.ID" and then just say "set Documents.DepartemntID = Selection.DepartemntID". Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries at all 

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
UPDATE Documents SET DepartemntID = E.DepartemntID
FROM Documents D
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT UserID, MIN(DepartemntID) DepartemntID
    FROM DepartmentsAndUsers
    GROUP BY UserID
) E ON E.UserID = D.AuthorID
```

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @Documents TABLE (
    DocumentID INT,
    AuthorID VARCHAR(16),
    DepartemntID VARCHAR(16)
)

DECLARE @DepartmentsAndUsers TABLE (
    DepartemntID VARCHAR(16),
    UserID VARCHAR(16)
)

INSERT @Documents VALUES
(1, 'User1', NULL),
(2, 'User2', NULL),
(3, 'User3', NULL),
(4, 'User1', NULL),
(5, 'User4', NULL)

INSERT @DepartmentsAndUsers VALUES
('Dept1', 'User1'),
('Dept1', 'User2'),
('Dept1', 'User3'),
('Dept2', 'User4'),
('Dept2', 'User5'),
('Dept3', 'User1'),
('Dept3', 'User3')

UPDATE @Documents SET DepartemntID = E.DepartemntID
FROM @Documents D
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT UserID, MIN(DepartemntID) DepartemntID
    FROM @DepartmentsAndUsers
    GROUP BY UserID
) E ON E.UserID = D.AuthorID

SELECT * FROM @Documents
```